# HTTPS Bad Gateway error in Wordpress site using ALB

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

I have a wordpress site which is implemented with ALB.I have got ACM and set up target groups for port 443 and 80. I've made a script for healthcheck like following link:

https://www.dylanbarlett.com/2015/06/elb-health-check-target-for-wordpress-networks/

It works fine with http(80) but it gives 502 Bad Gateway error using HTTPS(443). The ALB-healthcheck status for 443 is unhealthy. I have googled and tried different solutions but it still hasn't been fixed.

I have modified the following lines in wp-config.php:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
....
....
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://mywordpress.no' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://mywordpress.no' );
```

Added the following lines in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
  ServerName mywordpress.no
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mywordpress.no
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

 # This line is super important and will ensure that wordpress renders https links

  SetEnvIfNoCase X-FORWARDED-PROTO "^https$" HTTPS

  <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog /var/log/wordpress-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/wordpress-access.log combined

  RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

I have added .htaccess file which is like:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 # For a site running on port 443 or else (http over ssl)
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^80$
 RewriteRule !^wp-(admin|login|register)(.*) - [C]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L]

 # For a site running on port 80 (http)
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  ^80$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^wp-(admin|login|register)(.*) https://%  {SERVER_NAME}:10001/wp-$1$2 [L]

 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  ^80$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

Updated:

I have modified 443 listener in ALB to forward to http-targetgroup, now I works fine.

ALB config:

```
Listeners:
 HTTP : 80    forward to tg-http
 HTTPS : 443  forward to tg-http

Target-Groups:
 Port:     Protocol:
 80        HTTP

TargetGroup- HealthCheck:
 Protocol   HTTP
 Path   /wp-content/themes/example-theme/health-check.php
 Port   traffic port
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *The ALB-healthcheck status for 443 is unhealthy* suggests that you configured the ALB to expect the instance to speak HTTPS *to the balancer* on port 443, which wouldn't be correct.  You should probably be able to send all traffic to the instance as HTTP,  on port 80.  Show or describe your target group(s) from the ALB?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks a lot :) it fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  We should formulate this into a proper answer for the benefit of future visitors.  What exactly did you change?  Did you collapse two target groups in to one so that everything hits 80 (was 443 set for HTTPS?), or did you reconfigure the 443 target group from HTTPS to HTTP, or was it something else?  Add a comment, and I'll add an answer explaining the solution in more detail.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Hi, I had two target groups one for port 80 and one for port 443. I have removed targetgroup with port 443. Now I have only one tg (80) and I forwarded the listeners (80,443) to that tg. But I faced to another problem now, the admin page doesn't show up after I changed it for HTTPS. Do you have any idea for that?

Comment: The admin page issue is fixed by setting Security Group (allow all traffic from ALB to EC2) I have also commented part (# For a site running on port 80 (http)) from .htaccess file.